# MacOS 10.x cannot be installed?

Tags: catalina, install

Forgot the password for an iMac I hadn’t used in months.  Not capable of running Big Sur; had all available updates.  Got into recovery partition, and the menu no longer has a change password option.

So I tried to reinstall.  After more than twenty minutes of saying it was installing, it said “no packages available to install.”  And then Startup disk is empty!

Restart with option shows two choices: installer and recovery.

What next?